# Can Jekyll site.posts mirror a collection?

Tags: rubygems, yaml, jekyll

I'm trying to add Jekyll Archives functionality to a custom collection in a Jekyll site. However, I've realized [site.posts is hardcoded](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives/blob/815e72b60a7e1f687dba18276ad64639d3b24017/lib/jekyll-archives.rb#L34) into the gem. It seems the folks at jekyll-archives [are aware](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-archives/pull/88).

In the meantime, I'm wondering if I can come up with some sort of workaround. If Jekyll Archives expects site.posts, is it possible to set site.posts = site.some_other_collection in _config.yml?

Other ideas are welcome, but I'd like to avoid altering the gem directly. And if I must make use of a posts directory, then I'd like it to be automatically populated by another collection.

Comment: I can't expect a fix. There hasn't been related activity since February. And I'd rather not have to consistently re-patch every time they update

Comment: Noted. Any thoughts on YAML?

Comment: I would copy the plugin and customize it so it won't be replaced in the following updates, then check for new versions until they fix it.